# phpize is not working in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

I am not able to use phpize which I required during different work.

```
$ phpize
The program 'phpize' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install php7.0-dev
```

As output is suggesting me to run " sudo apt install php7.0-dev " . so after running it I am getting this

```
xxx:/etc/php$ sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php7.0-dev is already the newest version (7.0.33-13+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 95 not upgraded.
29 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
xxx:/etc/php$ phpize
The program 'phpize' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install php7.0-dev
```

current php version used -:

```
xxx:/etc/php$ php -v
PHP 7.2.25-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2019 07:41:59) ( NTS )
```

Comment: Are you sure you have one and only php installation?

Comment: in php info  i am getting this  PHP logo
PHP Version 7.2.25-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

how can i check that if multiple php installed

Comment: Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize7.2' in the top level source directory of the module